# How to make Glass Button ignore form's gradient?

Tags: c#, user-interface

There's some really great code for a glass button here: http://www.lukesw.net/articles/GlassButton.aspx

The only trouble I have with this button is that if I apply a gradient to my forms it affects the color of the button so that it's not quite what I chose at design time.  I don't know whether it's the code I'm using to apply the form gradient that's causing this or if the button is not totally opaque or what.  I tried fooling around with the button code a bit but didn't get anywhere.  You can get the code for the button at the link I posted above.  Below is the code I'm using for my form gradient which is located in the form itself right now:

```
    private Color _Color1 = Color.Gainsboro;
    private Color _Color2 = Color.Blue;
    private float _ColorAngle = 60f;

    public Color Color1
    {

        get { return _Color1; }
        set {
            _Color1 = value;
            this.Invalidate(); // Tell the Form to repaint itself
        }
    }

    public Color Color2
    {
        get { return _Color2; }
        set {
            _Color2 = value;
            this.Invalidate(); // Tell the Form to repaint itself
        }
    }

    public float ColorAngle
    {
        get { return _ColorAngle; }
        set {
            _ColorAngle = value;
            this.Invalidate(); // Tell the Form to repaint itself
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
        Rectangle rBackground = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush bBackground
            = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(rBackground,
                                              _Color1, _Color2, _ColorAngle);

        g.FillRectangle(bBackground, rBackground);
        bBackground.Dispose();
    }
```

Any pointers on how I can get this button to display the same at runtime as it does at design time would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's that the button isn't totally opaque - it's called a glass button because you can see through it.

Comment: @minitech That certainly makes sense, but I just wish I knew what to change in the button code to make it opaque.  I'm more interested in the glossy look than in it actually being see through :/

Comment: FYI: I obviously can't put a bounty on this now, but I'll throw some bounty points to whoever can answer this since I know it involves more work than usual in having to go d/l the source to the button and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `DrawButtonBackground` method in `GlowButton.cs`, just change the opacity to fully opaque (`255`):

```
#region " content "
using (GraphicsPath bb = CreateRoundRectangle(rect, 2))
{
    //int opacity = pressed ? 0xcc : 0x7f;
    int opacity = 255;
    using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, backColor)))
    {
        g.FillPath(br, bb);
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Ahh... I was trying to put opacity at 100 instead of 255.  Thanks!